# CSS Selector Issue

Tags: css, wordpress

html > body .home blog logged-in > div #wrapper > div #page > div .cats

I have a problem with selecting unordered lists (i.e ul > li.*class-name*  *class-name-number*) at the above dom location in CSS. I am working with a wordpress theme.

Basically could I have suggestions for the correct selector to use in order to influence this tag? I can provide a simplified html structure if it will help.

I've tried a number of selectors along the lines of:

(sometimes)#page (# or .)cats (sometimes)ul li(sometimes with *class name*)

EDIT: I've tried the selectors suggested in the wordpress docs.

html structure:

```
<body class='*dynamic*'>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="page">


<div id="header" role="banner">
        <h1><a href=""></a>Header</h1>
        <div class="description">Site info</div>
</div>

<div id="cats">
<ul>
<li class="page_item dynamically generated class"></li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li class="category_item dynamically generated class"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

It is the two list structures I'm having problems with

```
div#cats ul {
    font-size:24px;
}
```

This is testing style. When it's working, I'll be changing it.

As requested

FURTHER:
I think this must be some sort of inheritance problem, so I'm going to attempt a slash and burn approach.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't really understand your situation, but as a first measure, remove the `>` to make the selector less strict.

Comment: Post the html structure and actual selector you're having troubles with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is your selector, there are a few issues with it.

```
html > body .home blog logged-in > div #wrapper > div #page > div .cats
```

I'll make a few assumptions. Since you didn't provide actual code.

I presume with the first part (`html > body .home blog logged-in`) you're trying to match `<body class="home blog logged-in">`. The correct selector for matching exactly that would be: `body.home.blog.logged-in`, but in case you just want to match any of the classes, you need a selector for each of them. If they apply the same styling, you can have them as a comma separated list, like this:

```
body.home, body.blog, body.logged-in { ... }
```

The next part (`body > div #wrapper`) I assume you want to match `<body><div id="wrapper">`. The correct selector for that is `body > div#wrapper`. The current selector looks for `<body><div><anytag id="wrapper">`.

The same applies for the rest of your selector. I'm assuming you simply have extraneous white space in there, which cause the selector to not match. For more information on CSS selectors, see [documentation on W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html), or if you're looking for more basic stuff the [W3Schools tutorial on CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp).

**Update after added HTML:**

There is no need to have such a specific selector. You can match the lists with the selector:

```
/* Match both lists */
div#cats ul {}

/* Match first list */
div#cats ul:first-child {}

/* Match last list (CSS3) */
div#cats ul:last-child {}

/* Match items */
div#cats li.page-item {}
div#cats li.category-item {}
/* NOTE! Underscores are not legal characters in classes and ids */

/* Match generated class */
div#cats li.dynamically-generated-class {}

/* Match generated class filtered by two classes */
div#cats li.page-item.dynamically-generated-class {}
div#cats li.category-item.dynamically-generated-class {}
```

If you have no need for matching `.page-item` and `.category-item` specifically in the `div#cats` only (e.g. they are not present elsewhere on the page), there is no need for prefixing the selector with `div#cats`.

**Update 2**:

The CSS selector you've posted is correct for the html you posted. ([See my demo](http://nikc.kapsi.fi/dev/html/misc/selector.html)). Perhaps you have other rules which are affecting the result as well. Try adding a `border` to the rule, to see if it really is matching the correct element.

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) is a very useful debugging tool for Firefox, which let's you see all the css rules which are being applied to a element. Perhaps that can help you?

Comment: There is no white space in the selectors in source files. The selector provided was generated by the firefox web developer plugin and is otherwise accruate

Comment: Ah, I see I misunderstood that part of the question then. Answer was updated.

Comment: I tried a few variations on those selectors but none worked! I know this is the correct stylesheet, and I've been successfully editing it up to this point.

Comment: Please update your question with the css you're trying to apply.

Comment: Somehow it's cleared itself while I was commenting out sections of CSS. I've not actually changed any rules yet which is a bit confusing.
On a side-note, do you know any developer/designer streamlined css files for wordpress?

Comment: Sorry, I don't. I tend to roll my own. Glad you solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

use Firebug to check if the `div#cats ul` style is being applied. my guess is that it's being overwritten by another rule (maybe another stylesheet). you could try using !important like so

```
div#cats ul {font-size: 24px !important;}
```

or you could try a more specific rule like

```
div#cats ul li {font-size: 24px !important;}
```